# Ajax goes to error with status = 0, but Fiddler returns 200

Tags: ajax

Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            url: "/MyController/MyMethod",
            data: {
                items: grid.getAllRowIds()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;                    
            },
            error: function (a, b, c) {
                debugger;
            }
        });
```

The parameters are correct because the method in the controller is entered, but ajax doesn't go to success. It goes to error instead, with status code = 0. Fiddler says everything is ok.

What is going on?

And the response text is empty string.

Comment: Does the controller accept POST requests? What is the request you make with fiddler like? Maybe some headers are different or the url is not correct, compare them both thoroughly and you will likely find the issue

Comment: @IvayloSlavov I have [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] above the method in the controller.